# Calculating code hash for an authorize-enact style runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime, upgrade, code-hash

How to calculate the code hash for `fn authorize_upgrade` of `cumulus_pallet_parachain_system`?

As per crate `substrate-runtime-proposal-hash` been trying `BLAKE2B32(0x0103 | BLAKE2B32(wasm_bytes))` with no luck, i.e. `Error::Unauthorized`.

Comment: Why are you trying to calculate the hash and not call the function directly?

Comment: @joepetrowski I need the hash as func input [authorize_upgrade](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_pallet_parachain_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.authorize_upgrade) to kickoff the upgrade.

Comment: How are you kicking off the upgrade? That is likely the problem, not `authorize_upgrade`.

Comment: 1. `npx @polkadot/api-cli@beta --ws $provider --sudo --seed "$phrase" tx.parachainSystem.authorizeUpgrade $hash`; 2. `npx @polkadot/api-cli@beta --ws $provider --sudo --seed "$phrase" --params $wasm tx.parachainSystem.enactAuthorizedUpgrade`; with `$hash=0xdeadbeef..?` and `$wasm=./path/to/export-genesis-wasm-output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I see what you are trying to do. You don't need the hash of the `authorize_upgrade` call, you need it encoded and wrapped with sudo. Then, *anyone* (i.e. not just sudo) can submit `enact_authorized_upgrade` as an *unsigned* transaction.

You are getting the `Unauthorized` error because in sudo you are only providing the hash of the call, not `authorize_upgrade(<code_hash>)`.

Here's your solution (with examples taken from the latest Statemint upgrade):

First, you need the `authorize_upgrade` *call data,* not call hash:

[image: authorize-upgrade-call]

As in, you want: `0x01023ef62993199d2253ec1f49508e4cff7e6d293555e405ab024a0c87db5c5008c0`

Now you need to submit this as sudo. Statemint doesn't have sudo, so you can't copy this exactly, but it would be like:

```
npx @polkadot/api-cli@beta --ws $provider --sudo --seed "$phrase" tx.parachainSystem.authorizeUpgrade "0x01023ef62993199d2253ec1f49508e4cff7e6d293555e405ab024a0c87db5c5008c0"
```

If this is successful, you will see an `UpgradeAuthorized(code_hash)` event on the parachain.

Now that it's authorized, you can do the `enact_authorized_upgrade` part. Again, you do not need sudo for this.

[image: enact-authorized-upgrade]

I'm not super familiar with the CLI you are using, but you want to submit this as an *unsigned transaction.* In the screenshot, that would be the "Submit Unsigned" button.

If that is successful, you will see a `ValidationFunctionStored` event. Note that depending on your Relay Chain configuration (`config.validation_upgrade_delay`), the upgrade won't take place right away, but after the number of Relay Chain blocks in the config.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately, still stuck at the original question as the call data is just a derivative of the code hash - how did you calculate it?

Comment: Here's the PR that added the ability to the UI: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/5226

I'd consider adding it to the output of your builds, though. [SrTool](https://github.com/paritytech/srtool) for example gives you the blake256 hash when it builds the runtime.

Comment: Also added a feature request for the CLI: https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/issues/376

Comment: Thanks a ton for your profound support and follow-up. Really appreciate the `srtool` hint and `tools` PR <3